3-way switch without proper travelers
A series of 4 can lights was installed by an electrician a few years ago when we bought the house and controlled by a 3 way switch, but never operated correctly. While upgrading my switches, I thought I'd try to fix them. My partner hired the electrician while I was out of town 2 years ago. They told me the electrician just wired the light and didn't mess with the switches. They told him the switches didn't work correctly but could operate the light. They report he told them it's better not to mess with the switches because it can open up a lot of other problems and get really expensive. He said if the lights turn on and off, it's better just to leave it as is. He said he has some lights like that at his own house. When I call him, he says he moved out of state, doesn't remember the install, and can't help me troubleshoot over the phone. Semi-related, but not the point of the question: I suspect this guy is not, in fact, an electrician but rather a handyman who does some electrical work.
On opening the junction box in the attic, it looks like I'm going to have to redo the circuit, but I'm wondering if I've just misunderstood it. The circuit is wired as follows.
EDIT:
I've added a diagram to make it easier to understand how the circuit is set up.

All cables do have a ground, but I've ignored them in the diagram. To my understanding, this is clearly not wired for a 3-way switch. There are no travelers and there is a superfluous cable from the 4th light to SW2. Conductors I've labeled as hot test at ~120V from ground when the circuit is energized. Conductors I've labeled as neutral test as continuous to ground when the circuit is not energized.
Detailed description of the circuit:
There are four can lights. Three lights are fed directly from the attic junction box using 2 wire cables (14/2). The fourth light is fed with connections from the 3rd.
The junction box has 3 2 wire cables going to can lights, 2 2-wire cables going to separate switch junction boxes for SW1 and SW2, and 1 3-wire cable going to the switch junction box for SW1.
SW1 is in a switch junction box with a single pole switch for a separate light. It has the 3-wire cable in from the can light j box and a 2-wire cable in from the can light j box, as described. It also has a 2-wire cable going out to the separate light. That separate light and switch doesn't have any issues.
SW2 is in a switch junction box with another 3-way switch for a separate light that is on a different breaker circuit. That switch j box has the 2-wire cable coming in from the light j box, another 2-wire cable coming in (I believe it's from the 4th can light, but that's well underneath a duct, and I haven't been able to trace it definitively). The switch j box also has one 3-wire cable coming in to the separate 3-way switch on the other circuit. That separate 3-way switch has some problems with flickering lights, but doesn't appear to be related.
Now, looking at the light junction box, these are the connections. When referring to resistance to ground and voltage between ground, the connections in the light j box are maintained, but the switches have been pulled and wires separated in the switch j boxes.
6 ground wires are twisted and capped in a large red wire nut. 6 white wires are twisted and capped in a large red wire nut. They have 0 resistance between ground when the circuit is not energized, so I expect they are all acting as neutrals.  3 of the white wires trace to the 3 can lights, 2 trace to the SW1 junction box (one through the 3-wire cable, one through the 2-wire cable) and one traces to the SW2 junction box.
3 black wires are twisted and capped in a large red wire nut. They show 122-123 volts between ground when the circuit is energized, so I expect they are all acting as hots. 2 trace to SW1 j box (one through the 3-wire cable, one through the 2-wire cable) and one traces to the SW2 junction box.
3 black wires and one red wire are twisted and capped in a large red wire nut. Without the switches wired in, there is no continuity with ground and no voltage between ground. I expect this is intended to act as a switched hot. The 3 black wires trace to the 3 can lights (each via their own 2-wire cable) and the 1 red wire traces to the SW1 j box via the 3-wire cable.
When I opened things up to upgrade the switches, no switches were grounded, and the common on SW1 was connected directly to the line terminal on the single pole switch for the other light. A hot black wire was connected to the common terminal on SW2. Unfortunately, I did not document the rest of how they were wired initially. They could turn on the can lights when in some configurations, but didn't operate as a proper 3 way switch, where, regardless of the state of the other switch, any switch could toggle the light from on to off and vice versa.
The way I understand this, this system doesn't have proper travelers. There should be two conductors running between SW1 and SW2 that aren't connected to any other conductors other than those switches. I expect the following would fix it:

Fish a 2-wire cable up through the attic connecting the SW1 and SW2 j box directly. Label the insulated conductors with yellow tape. These will become the travelers.

Obviously, connect the grounds in each j box to the box and to the green ground terminal on each switch

For SW2 j box:
Cap off the black and white wires coming in from the 4th can light. Cap off the white (neutral) coming in from the light j box.
Connect the black (hot) to the common terminal on SW2
Connect the white (with yellow tape) and black (with yellow tape) travelers to the traveler terminals on SW2.

For SW1 j box:
Cap off the white (neutral) coming in from the light j box via the 3-wire cable.
Cap off the black (hot) coming in from the light j box via the 3-wire cable.
Connect the red (switched hot) to the common terminal on SW1
Connect the white (with yellow tape) and black (with yellow tape) travelers to the traveler terminals on SW1.


Use the 2-wire cable coming in to the SW1 junction box for the separate switch that controls the other light.
Potential issues:

I have a capped hot in the SW2 junction box that I'm not using. I don't know if that's a code problem, but it's not ideal.
I have conductors going between SW1 and SW2 that are in separate cables. I think that might be a code issue, but I think it's not an actual safety problem, as they are still running in an insulated cable.
6 14g white wires in a single large red wire nut seems bad, but I always struggle to figure out how to tie that many conductors together in a normal size j box, so I really don't want to mess with it.

Specific question: is my proposed solution safe and effective? Am I missing a proper way to wire the 3-way switches with the existing configuring? I expect the best solution is to pull both 2-wire cables feeding the SW2 junction box, remove them from their connections, and run a 3-wire cable between the SW1 and SW2 junction box, and wire it like 3-way switches are supposed to be wired, but I'd rather not mess with any of the connections in the light junction box or have to pull cables that are connected to studs. I'm not even sure how to do that without opening up walls.
I'm including photos of the light junction box (open and closed) in the attic.



The text description is unfortunately hard to follow. Can you please draw the wiring that you see?

@Triplefault I hear you. It's complicated written or drawn. I'm not familiar with any circuit drawing software. There are a LOT of wires. Would a photo of a hand drawn diagram really help more than text describing where each wire is and is connected?

Yes, a hand-drawn sketch would probably work fine.


Fish a 2-wire cable up through the attic connecting the SW1 and SW2 j box directly.

I think there is a way to make this compatible with the literal meaning of NEC 300.3(B), but I would also recommend using a 14/3 cable instead.  The third wire will make the whole situation less confusing.

For SW1 j box: Cap off the white (neutral) coming in from the light j box via the 3-wire cable. Cap off the black (hot) coming in from the light j box via the 3-wire cable. Connect the red (switched hot) to the common terminal

This is where you would violate NEC 300.3(B).  A switched hot wire can't go in its own separate cable when there's a neutral for the same circuit going to the same place.
The simplest way to solve this is to use SW2 for switched hot power.  You already have a cable from SW2 to one of the lights, so the cable from SW2 to the attic isn't needed.
You also mentioned there are two circuits in the SW2 box.  Make sure none of the circuit conductors are connected between the circuits.  Only the bare ground wires (EGC) may be connected between circuits.

To clarify, the red wire in SW1 is not presently switched hot. It would be if connected to the common terminal of SW1, as constant hot is connected to the common terminal of SW1 in my proposed solution.  But I'm not clear what your solution is. Are you saying I should connect a constant hot to the common of SW1 and use the black wire from the fourth light as the switched hot (common of SW2)?

I think this is a product of a difficult to follow description, but the red wire from the SW1 junction box is tied to the 3 black wires that feed to the can lights from the light junction box (and subsequently feed the 4th). So there's an equivalent conductor going from SW1 and SW2, it's just the one from SW1 connects at the main junction box for the can lights, where the one from SW2 connects at one light. I've edited my question to include a hand drawn diagram.

@DeNovo You will need to decide how liberal to be with interpreting NEC 300.3(B).  Adding a 14/3 cable between the switches allows for balanced current and all conductors can be in one cable for each path.  Without that, you would have to do something like putting the travelers in a cable that doesn't have a return wire.  There are plenty of wires in the diagram, just not enough of them in each cable.
